# Same IP adresseses are working fine in my hostel. How is it possibe?

Tags: ip

Me and my friend are using the same IP address however we are getting no error message of IP conflict. How is it working. We are receiving the data that we requested for and so how is this possible?

Comment: Are you on the same subnet? Do you see the same hosts on a network scan? Large hostels often have multiple routers with same SSID and PSK, this allows you to connect to the strongest signal. Some devices have weird signal-strenght based network preferences.

Comment: yes , we are on the same subnet and host is same as well

Comment: Can you ping eachother? This is done on IP basis and receiving packets is done on mac address basis.

Comment: I have cloned his mac address as my mac address was blocked by network administrator. we are having same mac as well .- :p

Comment: I'm starting to suspect the router firmware is quite hackily coded. Wireless or physical connection to the router?

Comment: Currently, I am connected through physical. but I have the same experience on wireless link as well

Comment: That router creeps me out. I don't understand how it does not crash. I can't help you further. Have a nice day.

Comment: It's posessed by cthulhu the ipv4 dark lord

Answer (score 0):

When you clone the MAC address you are likely to be assigned the same IP address.  As you both have the same MAC address, there is no conflict in the ARP tables as you both answer with the same MAC address.

IP is quiet resilient to conditions like this.  If you both browse the same site you may run into problems.   It is also possible for your stack to close connections made by his stack of vice versa.  Closing connections for the other computer can be nasty, but may not be completed before you have gotten the data you were looking for.

Even without cloned MAC addresses, both computers could be quite functional.  Without appropriate ARP data it can be quite difficult to detect the problem.